# how to replace a html function call by a typescript function call?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is how my div looks like inside html:

```
<div class="form-group col">
  <label for="randomName" class="mb-1">Test</label>
  <ngb-timepicker id="randomName" name="start" [(ngModel)]="startTime"
                  [acSmallestTimeUnit]="this.smallestTimeUnit"
                  [acSmallestTimeUnitEnabled]="this.smallestTimeUnitEnabled" [spinners]="false"
                  #start="ngModel"></ngb-timepicker>
</div>
```

I use a template driven approach for custom validation here. Whenever i change the value of another html element, i would like to trigger the validation of the start element manually. I do that by using the method updateValueAndValidity(). Like this:

```
<select (change)="onChange(); start.control.updateValueAndValidity();" 
        id="random" class="form-control" #project name="project"
        [(ngModel)]="projectName" #project="ngModel" tabIndex="0" required>
```

The problem is, i have to call start.control.updateValueAndValidity() after onChange(). But onChange() is asynchronous so in order to call start.control.updateValueAndValidity() after onChange() i would like to call it at the end of the onChange() method which is written in typescript using async and await. I would like to know how to transform the start.control.updateValueAndValitiy() to typescript code so i can call it there, i do not really know how to get the start value. I tried multiple things including document.getElementByName() etc., but nothing worked yet.

Comment: Why don't you move `start.control.updateValueAndValidity()` into `onChange` and call it in proper place?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to pass `start` to `onChange` and call `start.control.updateValueAndValidity()` within `onChange`

```html
<select (change)="onChange(start)" 
        id="random" class="form-control" #project name="project"
        [(ngModel)]="projectName" #project="ngModel" tabIndex="0" required>
```

```js
onChange(start) {
   // some async await call

   start.control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that approach should be working. But theres a problem for some reason. As you see in the code above, i have the following binding `[acSmallestTimeUnit]="this.smallestTimeUnit"`. So whenever i call the validation, the validation class gets an input. I update the this.smallestTimeUnit value before i call `start.control.updateValueAndValidity();` but for some reason the validation still gets the old value. I checked it and `this.smallestTimeUnit` is surely changed before i call the function, i do not know why it still uses the old value on the validation when i trigger it manually.

Comment: @Votic98 did you try to use `ngModelChange` instead of `change`? Also, make sure you put it after `[(ngModel)]="projectName"`

Comment: Yes, i just tried that and it did not help. It works if i wait like 10 ms before calling the function with `setTimeout(function() {
      start.control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }, 10);`, but that can not be the solution, because it may cause problems. It seems like it takes some time till the new value gets saved with the binding and the call happens before that?

Comment: If you could create a stackblitz that reproduces your problem, I would be more helpful. It is really hard to say anything without running it.